# Decomposing a Tensor Product of $SU(3)$ Representations in Irreps

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, group-theory, group-representations

Can somebody explain in a simple way why, talking about representations $$3\otimes3\otimes3=1\oplus8\oplus8\oplus10~?$$

Here $3$ and $\bar{3}$ are the fundamental and anti-fundamental of $SU(3)$, in this case.

Comment: Related $SU(3)$ post: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10403/2451 especially the answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/14586/2451 . Do you know Clebsch-Gordan decomposition of $SU(2)$ irreps? See e.g. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16098/2451 .

Comment: I found the group theory appendix (B) in [Zee, Quantum Field Theory in a Nutshell](http://www.amazon.com/Quantum-Field-Theory-Nutshell-Princeton/dp/0691140340/ref=tmm_hrd_title_0), to be helpful for this stuff.

Comment: Removed subquestions that are duplicates in v3: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/147243/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89173/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 2):

---

\begin{equation}   
\boldsymbol{3}\boldsymbol{\otimes}\boldsymbol{3}\boldsymbol{\otimes}\boldsymbol{3}=
\boldsymbol{1}\boldsymbol{\oplus}\boldsymbol{10}\boldsymbol{\oplus}
\boldsymbol{8}^{\boldsymbol{\prime}}\boldsymbol{\oplus}\boldsymbol{8}
\end{equation}

We talk about this because it explains the structure of a number of baryons in Particle Physics made from three quarks : 1 singlet  - 1 decuplet - 2 octets,  that is 27 baryons in total.
 I refer to my answer in the following link for more details :

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1091189

---