# Anti-triplet representation

Tags: terminology, group-theory, definition, representation-theory

What is the anti-triplet representation of a group?

Specifically, what is the anti-triplet representation of $SU(3)$?

Comment: May be my answers as user82794 here : [How to get result  3x3=6+3¯  for  SU(3)  irreducible representations?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/147243/) and here :
[SU(3) decomposition of 3x3¯=8+1?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89173/) could help you a little.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mathematician will give more detailed and rigorous answer. From the physicist point of view, representation corresponds to the way the object transforms under a symmetry group $G$. Let us assign upper index to the object $a^{i}$, that transforms like a column under $G$:
$$
a^{i} \rightarrow U_j^{i} \ a^{j} 
$$
This we will call the fundamental representation. For the case of $SU(N)$ the fundamental representation is a column of $N$-elements. The object with the lower index $b_i$ we will regard as transforming in antifundamental representation (it will reside in the dual vector space to the fundamental).
$$
b_i \rightarrow (U^*)_{i}^{ j} b_j
$$
This object will transform as a row, or ,looking in another way, as a column, but under the hermitian conjugated matrix $U^{\dagger}$. For the case of $SU(N)$ think about it as row of $N$ complex numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The anti-triplet representation $\bar{\bf 3}$ is presumably the [complex conjugate representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate_representation) of the defining/[fundamental](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_representation) $SU(3)$ representation ${\bf 3}$.