# How to get result $3 \otimes 3 = 6 \oplus \bar{3}$ for $SU(3)$ irreducible representations?

Tags: group-theory, group-representations, tensor-calculus, lie-algebra, representation-theory

Let's have $SU(3)$ irreducible representations $3, \bar{3}$. How to get result that
$$
3\otimes 3 =6  \oplus \bar{3}~?
$$
I'm interested in $\bar{3}$ part. It's clear that for $3 \otimes 3$ we can use tensor rules by expanding corresponding matrix on symmetric $6$ and antisymmetric parts. But why we have $\bar{3}$, not $3$, for antisymmetric part?

Comment: Are you familiar with Young tableux?

Comment: Related $SU(3)$ post: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10403/2451 and links therein; especially the answer http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/14586/2451 .

Comment: @Innisfree : yes, I know something about it. Qmechanic, thank you. I'll check it.

Answer (score 16):

**Section A :** *The connection of the transformations of complex $\:3\times 3\:$ antisymmetric tensors and their representative complex $\:3$-vectors.*

---

Let $\:U\:$ be a special unitary transformation in $\:SU(3)\:$ represented by the $\:3\times 3\:$ complex matrix
\begin{equation}
U=
\begin{bmatrix}
  u_{11} & u_{12} & u_{13} \\
  u_{21} & u_{22} & u_{23} \\
  u_{31} & u_{32} & u_{33}
\end{bmatrix} 
\tag{A-01}
\end{equation}
Since $\:UU^{\boldsymbol{*}}=I\:$ we have $\:U^{\boldsymbol{*}}=U^{-1}$, so 
\begin{equation}
U^{\boldsymbol{*}}=\left(\overline{U}\right)^{\mathsf{T}}=\overline{U^{\mathsf{T}}}
\begin{bmatrix}
  \overline{u}_{11} & \overline{u}_{21} & \overline{u}_{31} \\
  \overline{u}_{12} & \overline{u}_{22} & \overline{u}_{32} \\
  \overline{u}_{13} & \overline{u}_{23} & \overline{u}_{33}
\end{bmatrix}
= U^{-1}
\tag{A-02}
\end{equation}
where $\:\overline{u}\:$ = the complex conjugate of $\:u\:$ and $\:U^{\mathsf{T}}\:$ the transpose matrix of $\:U$.
By $\:\det\left(U\right)=1$  we have
\begin{equation}
U^{-1}=
\begin{bmatrix}
  (u_{22}u_{33}-u_{23}u_{32}) & (u_{13}u_{32}-u_{12}u_{33}) & (u_{12}u_{23}-u_{13}u_{22}) \\
  (u_{23}u_{31}-u_{21}u_{33}) & (u_{11}u_{33}-u_{13}u_{31}) & (u_{13}u_{21}-u_{11}u_{23}) \\
  (u_{21}u_{32}-u_{22}u_{31}) & (u_{12}u_{31}-u_{11}u_{32}) & (u_{11}u_{22}-u_{12}u_{21})
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{A-03}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
U^{-1}=
\begin{bmatrix}
+ \begin{vmatrix}
   u_{22} & u_{23}\\
   u_{32} & u_{33}
  \end{vmatrix} & 
    -  \begin{vmatrix}
       u_{12} & u_{13}\\
       u_{32} & u_{33}
      \end{vmatrix} & 
         +\begin{vmatrix}
           u_{12} & u_{13}\\
           u_{22} & u_{23}
          \end{vmatrix} \\
  &&\\
- \begin{vmatrix}
   u_{21} & u_{23}\\
   u_{31} & u_{33}
  \end{vmatrix} & 
    +  \begin{vmatrix}
       u_{11} & u_{13}\\
       u_{31} & u_{33}
      \end{vmatrix} & 
        -  \begin{vmatrix}
           u_{11} & u_{13}\\
           u_{21} & u_{23}
          \end{vmatrix} \\
   &&\\         
+ \begin{vmatrix}
   u_{21} & u_{22}\\
   u_{31} & u_{32}
  \end{vmatrix} & 
   -  \begin{vmatrix}
       u_{11} & u_{12}\\
       u_{31} & u_{32}
      \end{vmatrix} & 
       +  \begin{vmatrix}
           u_{11} & u_{12}\\
           u_{21} & u_{22}
          \end{vmatrix} 
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{A-03$^{\prime}$}
\end{equation}

By equations (A-02) and (A-03) the complex conjugate of the elements $\:U\:$ are expressed
in terms of the elements themselves
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
  \overline{u}_{11} & \overline{u}_{21} & \overline{u}_{31} \\
  \overline{u}_{12} & \overline{u}_{22} & \overline{u}_{32} \\
  \overline{u}_{13} & \overline{u}_{23} & \overline{u}_{33}
\end{bmatrix}
\\=
\begin{bmatrix}
  (u_{22}u_{33}-u_{23}u_{32}) & (u_{32}u_{13}-u_{33}u_{12}) & (u_{12}u_{23}-u_{13}u_{22}) \\
  (u_{23}u_{31}-u_{21}u_{33}) & (u_{33}u_{11}-u_{31}u_{13}) & (u_{13}u_{21}-u_{11}u_{23}) \\
  (u_{21}u_{32}-u_{22}u_{31}) & (u_{31}u_{12}-u_{32}u_{11}) & (u_{11}u_{22}-u_{12}u_{21})
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{A-04}
\end{equation}
that is $\:\overline{u}_{11}=u_{22}u_{33}-u_{23}u_{32}\:$,$\:\overline{u}_{21}=u_{32}u_{13}-u_{33}u_{12}\:$... etc.

Now let $\:\boldsymbol{\omega}=\left(\omega_{1},\omega_{2}, \omega_{3}\right)\:$ a complex $\:3$-vector in $\:\mathbb{C}^{3}\:$ and $\:\mathrm{\Omega}\:$ the antisymmetric matrix representing the operation $\:\boldsymbol{\omega}\boldsymbol{\times}\:$

\begin{equation}
\mathrm{\Omega}=
\begin{bmatrix}
       0     & -\omega_{3} &  \omega_{2} \\
  \omega_{3} &      0      & -\omega_{1} \\
 -\omega_{2} &  \omega_{1} &      0
\end{bmatrix}
=\boldsymbol{\omega}\boldsymbol{\times}
\tag{A-05}
\end{equation}
Suppose that $\:\boldsymbol{\omega}\:$ is transformed to $\:\boldsymbol{\omega}^{\prime}\:$ under a special unitary transformation $\:U \in SU(3)\:$
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{\omega}^{\prime}=U\boldsymbol{\omega}
\tag{A-06}
\end{equation}
and $\:\mathrm{\Omega}^{\prime}\:$ the antisymmetric matrix representing the operation $\:\boldsymbol{\omega}^{\prime}\boldsymbol{\times}\:$
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{\Omega}^{\prime}=
\begin{bmatrix}
       0     & -\omega^{\prime}_{3} &  \omega^{\prime}_{2} \\
  \omega^{\prime}_{3} &      0      & -\omega^{\prime}_{1} \\
 -\omega^{\prime}_{2} &  \omega^{\prime}_{1} &      0
\end{bmatrix}
=\boldsymbol{\omega}^{\prime}\boldsymbol{\times}
\tag{A-07}
\end{equation}
We'll determine now the relation between the antisymmetric matrices  $\:\mathrm{\Omega}^{\prime}\:$ and $\:\mathrm{\Omega}$. For any $\:\mathbf{z} \in \mathbb{C}^{3}\:$
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{\Omega}^{\prime}\mathbf{z}=\boldsymbol{\omega}^{\prime}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{z}
=U\boldsymbol{\omega}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{z}=U\boldsymbol{\omega}\boldsymbol{\times} UU^{\boldsymbol{*}}\mathbf{z}=\left[\;\det\left(U\right)\cdot\left(U^{-1}\right)^{\mathsf{T}}\; \right]\left(\boldsymbol{\omega}\boldsymbol{\times}U^{\boldsymbol{*}}\mathbf{z}\right)
\tag{A-08}
\end{equation}
For the last to the right equality in (A-08) we make use of the identity

\begin{equation}
 \bbox[#E6E6E6,8px]{\boldsymbol{\mathrm{M}}\mathbf{a} \boldsymbol{\times} \boldsymbol{\mathrm{M}}\mathbf{b} =
\left[\;\det\left(\boldsymbol{\mathrm{M}}\right)\cdot\left(\boldsymbol{\mathrm{M}}^{-1}\right)^{\mathsf{T}}\; \right]\left(\mathbf{a} \boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{b}\right)}
\tag{B-02}
\end{equation}
exposed and proved in section B.

Since $\:\det\left(U\right)=1\:$ and  $\:U^{-1}=U^{\boldsymbol{*}}\:$
\begin{equation*}
\left[\det\left(U\right)\cdot\left(U^{-1}\right)^{\mathsf{T}}\right]
\left(\boldsymbol{\omega}\boldsymbol{\times}U^{\boldsymbol{*}}\mathbf{z}\right)
=\left[\left(U^{\boldsymbol{*}}\right)^{\mathsf{T}}\left(\boldsymbol{\omega}\boldsymbol{\times}\right) U^{\boldsymbol{*}}\right]\mathbf{z}=\left[\left(U^{\boldsymbol{*}}\right)^{\mathsf{T}}\mathrm{\Omega} U^{\boldsymbol{*}}\right]\mathbf{z}=\left[\overline{U}\mathrm{\Omega}
 \left(\overline{U}\right)^{\mathsf{T}}\right]\mathbf{z}
\end{equation*}
so finaly
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{\omega}^{\prime}=U\boldsymbol{\omega}\qquad\Longrightarrow\qquad
\mathrm{\Omega}^{\prime}=\left(U^{\boldsymbol{*}}\right)^{\mathsf{T}}\mathrm{\Omega} U^{\boldsymbol{*}}=\overline{U}\mathrm{\Omega} \left(\overline{U}\right)^{\mathsf{T}}
\tag{A-09}
\end{equation}
Since $\:\overline{U}\:$ is also a special unitary transformation,$\:\overline{U}\in SU(3)\:$, replacing $\:U\:$ by $\:\overline{U}\:$ in above equation (A-09) we have

\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{\omega}^{\prime}=\overline{U}\boldsymbol{\omega}\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
\mathrm{\Omega}^{\prime}=U\mathrm{\Omega}U^{\mathsf{T}}
\tag{A-10}
\end{equation}
Note that the two equations in (A-10) are equivalent in the following sense :
 If $\:\mathrm{\Omega}\:$ is a  $\:3\times 3\:$ antisymmetric matrix, so representing the product $\:\boldsymbol{\omega}\boldsymbol{\times}\:$ where $\:\boldsymbol{\omega} \in \mathbb{C}^{3}$, and $\mathrm{\Omega}^{\prime}=U\mathrm{\Omega}U^{\mathsf{T}}$,where $U \in SU(3)$, then $\:\mathrm{\Omega}^{\prime}\:$ is also a $\:3\times 3\:$ antisymmetric matrix

\begin{equation*}
\text{Proof  :  }
\left(\mathrm{\Omega}^{\prime}\right)^{\mathsf{T}}
=\left(U\mathrm{\Omega}U^{\mathsf{T}}\right)^{\mathsf{T}}
=\left(U^{\mathsf{T}}\right)^{\mathsf{T}}\mathrm{\Omega}^{\mathsf{T}}U^{\mathsf{T}}
=U\left(-\mathrm{\Omega}\right)U^{\mathsf{T}}=-U\mathrm{\Omega}U^{\mathsf{T}}
=-\mathrm{\Omega}^{\prime}  
\end{equation*}
and represents the product $\:\boldsymbol{\omega}^{\prime}\boldsymbol{\times}\:$,
where $\:\boldsymbol{\omega}^{\prime}=\overline{U}\boldsymbol{\omega}\:$.

\begin{equation}
 \bbox[#FFFF88,8px]{\mathrm{\Omega}^{\prime}=U\mathrm{\Omega}U^{\mathsf{T}}\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad
\boldsymbol{\omega}^{\prime}=\overline{U}\boldsymbol{\omega}}
\tag{A-10$^{\prime}$}
\end{equation}
This is confirmed also by equating by elements in the equation 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
       0     & -\omega^{\prime}_{3} &  \omega^{\prime}_{2} \\
  \omega^{\prime}_{3} &      0      & -\omega^{\prime}_{1} \\
 -\omega^{\prime}_{2} &  \omega^{\prime}_{1} &      0
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
  u_{11} & u_{12} & u_{13} \\
  u_{21} & u_{22} & u_{23} \\
  u_{31} & u_{32} & u_{33}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
       0     & -\omega_{3} &  \omega_{2} \\
  \omega_{3} &      0      & -\omega_{1} \\
 -\omega_{2} &  \omega_{1} &      0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  u_{11} & u_{21} & u_{31} \\
  u_{12} & u_{22} & u_{32} \\
  u_{13} & u_{23} & u_{33}
\end{bmatrix}  
\end{equation*}
yielding
\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
   \omega^{\prime}_{1} \\
   \omega^{\prime}_{2} \\
   \omega^{\prime}_{3} 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
  (u_{22}u_{33}-u_{23}u_{32}) &(u_{23}u_{31}-u_{21}u_{33}) & (u_{21}u_{32}-u_{22}u_{31}) \\
  (u_{32}u_{13}-u_{33}u_{12} & (u_{33}u_{11}-u_{31}u_{13}) & (u_{31}u_{12}-u_{32}u_{11}) \\
  (u_{12}u_{23}-u_{13}u_{22} & (u_{13}u_{21}-u_{11}u_{23}) & (u_{11}u_{22}-u_{12}u_{21})
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
   \omega_{1} \\
   \omega_{2} \\
   \omega_{3} 
\end{bmatrix}  
\end{equation*}
and so by (A-04)
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{\omega}^{\prime}=\overline{U}\boldsymbol{\omega}
\tag{A-11}
\end{equation}

*Note:* This result has to do with a first step for the construction of baryons from 3 quarks
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{3}\boldsymbol{\otimes}\boldsymbol{3}=\boldsymbol{6}\boldsymbol{\oplus}\overline{\boldsymbol{3}}
\tag{A-12}
\end{equation}

The invariance of ( the complex $\:3\times 3\:$ tensor's ) antisymmetry  under $\:U \in SU(3)\:$ is the invariance of the complex $\:3$-dimensional space of their  representative $\:3$-vectors $\:\boldsymbol{\omega}\:$,  ***which are transformed under*** $\:\overline{U}\:$ ***and not under*** $\:U\:$. This explains why $\:\overline{\boldsymbol{3}}\:$ and not $\:\boldsymbol{3}$.

If  $\:U=\overline{U}=\mathrm{M}$, that is $\:U\:$ is real, then it represents a pure rotation in $\:\mathbb{R}^{3}\:$,$\:\mathrm{M}^{\mathsf{T}}=\mathrm{M}^{-1}\:$ and (A-10$^{\prime}$) yields
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{\Omega}^{\prime}=\mathrm{M}\mathrm{\Omega}\mathrm{M}^{-1}\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad
\boldsymbol{\omega}^{\prime}=\mathrm{M}\boldsymbol{\omega}
\tag{A-13}
\end{equation}

---

**Section B** : *A useful identity necessary in section A*

---

If $\:\mathbf{a}= \left( \mathrm{a}_{1}, \mathrm{a}_{2}, \mathrm{a}_{3}\right),\:\mathbf{b}= \left( \mathrm{b}_{1}, \mathrm{b}_{2}, \mathrm{b }_{3}\right) $ are complex $\:3$-vectors  in $\:\mathbb{C}^{3}\:$ and $\:\boldsymbol{\mathrm{M}}\:$ an invertible linear transformation in this space represented by the $\:3\times 3\:$ complex matrix
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{\mathrm{M}}=
\begin{bmatrix}
  \mathrm{M}_{11} & \mathrm{M}_{12} & \mathrm{M}_{13} \\
  \mathrm{M}_{21} & \mathrm{M}_{22} & \mathrm{M}_{23} \\
  \mathrm{M}_{31} & \mathrm{M}_{32} & \mathrm{M}_{33}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
  \boldsymbol{\rho}_{1} \\
  \boldsymbol{\rho}_{2} \\
  \boldsymbol{\rho}_{3} 
\end{bmatrix} 
\tag{B-01}
\end{equation}
where $\:\boldsymbol{\rho}_{i}\; (i=1,2,3)\:$ denote its row complex $\:3$-vectors, then
\begin{equation}
 \bbox[#E6E6E6,8px]{\boldsymbol{\mathrm{M}}\mathbf{a} \boldsymbol{\times} \boldsymbol{\mathrm{M}}\mathbf{b} =
\left[\;\det\left(\boldsymbol{\mathrm{M}}\right)\cdot\left(\boldsymbol{\mathrm{M}}^{-1}\right)^{\mathsf{T}}\; \right]\left(\mathbf{a} \boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{b}\right)}
\tag{B-02}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
   \det \left(\boldsymbol{\mathrm{M}}\right) =\text{the determinant of } \boldsymbol{\mathrm{M}} =  \boldsymbol{\rho}_{1}\circ \left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{2} \boldsymbol{\times}\boldsymbol{\rho}_{3}\right)
\tag{B-03}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\left(\boldsymbol{\mathrm{M}}^{-1}\right)^{\mathsf{T}} = \text{the transposed inverse of} \: \boldsymbol{\mathrm{M}}=
\dfrac{1}{\det\left(\boldsymbol{\mathrm{M}}\right)}
\begin{bmatrix}
  \left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{2} \boldsymbol{\times}\boldsymbol{\rho}_{3}\right)  \\ 
  \left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{3} \boldsymbol{\times}\boldsymbol{\rho}_{1}\right)  \\ 
  \left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{1} \boldsymbol{\times}\boldsymbol{\rho}_{2}\right) 
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{B-04}
\end{equation}
The expression $\:\mathbf{a}\circ\mathbf{b}\:$ is defined by
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{a}\circ\mathbf{b}=\mathrm{a}_{1}\mathrm{b}_{1}+\mathrm{a}_{2}\mathrm{b}_{2}+\mathrm{a}_{3}\mathrm{b}_{3}
\tag{B-05}
\end{equation}
not to be confused with the usual inner product in $\:\mathbb{C}^{3}\:$
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{\langle}\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}\boldsymbol{\rangle}=\mathrm{a}_{1}\overline{\mathrm{b}}_{1}+\mathrm{a}_{2}\overline{\mathrm{b}}_{2}+\mathrm{a}_{3}\overline{\mathrm{b}}_{3}
\tag{B-06}
\end{equation} 
**Proof:**
Let 
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{h}=\boldsymbol{\mathrm{M}}\mathbf{a} \boldsymbol{\times}\boldsymbol{\mathrm{M}}\mathbf{b}
\end{equation*}
If  $\:\left\lbrace \mathbf{e}_{1}, \mathbf{e}_{2},  \mathbf{e}_{3}\right\rbrace\:$  is an orthonormal base of $\:\mathbb{C}^{3}\:$ then one can formally write, for any two row vectors
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{\rho} \boldsymbol{\times}\boldsymbol{\sigma}
 =
\begin{vmatrix}
  \mathbf{e}_{1}    & \mathbf{e}_{2}     &  \mathbf{e}_{3}   \\
  \rho_1 & \rho_2 &  \rho_3 \\
  \sigma_1 & \sigma_2 &  \sigma_3 
\end{vmatrix}
\end{equation}
("formally" because a determinant is number, here the $\mathbf{e}_i$ are vectors). Hence
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{h}  = 
\begin{vmatrix}
  \mathbf{e}_{1} & \mathbf{e}_{2} & \mathbf{e}_{3} \\
  \left( \mathrm{M}_{11}\mathrm{a}_{1}+\mathrm{M}_{12}\mathrm{a}_{2} +\mathrm{M}_{13}\mathrm{a}_{3}\right)  &  \left( \mathrm{M}_{21}\mathrm{a}_{1}+\mathrm{M}_{22}\mathrm{a}_{2} +\mathrm{M}_{23}\mathrm{a}_{3}\right) &  \left( \mathrm{M}_{31}\mathrm{a}_{1}+\mathrm{M}_{32}\mathrm{a}_{2} +\mathrm{M}_{33}\mathrm{a}_{3}\right) \\
  \left( \mathrm{M}_{11}\mathrm{b}_{1}+\mathrm{M}_{12}\mathrm{b}_{2} +\mathrm{M}_{13}\mathrm{b}_{3}\right)  &  \left( \mathrm{M}_{21}\mathrm{b}_{1}+\mathrm{M}_{22}\mathrm{b}_{2} +\mathrm{M}_{23}\mathrm{b}_{3}\right) &  \left( \mathrm{M}_{31}\mathrm{b}_{1}+\mathrm{M}_{32}\mathrm{b}_{2} +\mathrm{M}_{33}\mathrm{b}_{3}\right)
\end{vmatrix}
\end{equation}
or in more compact form
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{h} =
\begin{vmatrix}
  \mathbf{e}_{1} & \mathbf{e}_{2} & \mathbf{e}_{3} \\
  \left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{1}\circ\mathbf{a}\right)  &  \left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{2}\circ\mathbf{a}\right) &  \left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{3}\circ\mathbf{a}\right) \\
 \left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{1}\circ\mathbf{b}\right)  &  \left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{2}\circ\mathbf{b}\right) &  \left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{3}\circ\mathbf{b}\right)  
\end{vmatrix}
\end{equation*}
so
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \mathrm{h}_{1}
  & = &
  \left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{2}\circ \mathbf{a}\right)\left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{3}\circ\mathbf{b}\right)
  -\left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{2}\circ\mathbf{b}\right)\left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{3}\circ\mathbf{a}\right)\\
  & = & \boldsymbol{\rho}_{2}\circ\underbrace{\left[\left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{3}\circ\mathbf{b}\right)\mathbf{a}
  -\left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{3}\circ\mathbf{a}\right)\mathbf{b}\right]}
  _{\boldsymbol{\rho}_{3}\boldsymbol{\times}\left(\mathbf{a} \boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{b}\right)}
  = \boldsymbol{\rho}_{2}\circ\left[\boldsymbol{\rho}_{3}\boldsymbol{\times}\left(\mathbf{a} \boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{b}\right)\right]\\
  & = &
  \left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{2} \boldsymbol{\times}\boldsymbol{\rho}_{3}\right) \circ \left(\mathbf{a} \boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{b}\right)  
\end{eqnarray*}
that is
\begin{equation*}
\mathrm{h}_{1}=\left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{2} \boldsymbol{\times}\boldsymbol{\rho}_{3}\right) \circ \left(\mathbf{a} \boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{b}\right)   
\end{equation*}
and by cyclic permutation of the indices 1,2,3 we have for the other two components
\begin{equation*}
\mathrm{h}_{2}=\left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{3} \boldsymbol{\times}\boldsymbol{\rho}_{1}\right) \circ \left(\mathbf{a} \boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{b}\right)   
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\mathrm{h}_{3}=\left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{1} \boldsymbol{\times}\boldsymbol{\rho}_{2}\right) \circ \left(\mathbf{a} \boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{b}\right)   
\end{equation*}
and finally
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{h}=\boldsymbol{\mathrm{M}}\mathbf{a} \boldsymbol{\times}\boldsymbol{\mathrm{M}}\mathbf{b} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
  \left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{2} \boldsymbol{\times}\boldsymbol{\rho}_{3}\right)  \\ 
  \left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{3} \boldsymbol{\times}\boldsymbol{\rho}_{1}\right) \\ 
  \left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{1} \boldsymbol{\times}\boldsymbol{\rho}_{2}\right) 
\end{bmatrix}
\left( \mathbf{a} \boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{b} \right)
= \left[\;\det\left(\boldsymbol{\mathrm{M}}\right)\cdot\left(\boldsymbol{\mathrm{M}}^{-1}\right)^{\mathsf{T}}\; \right]\left(\mathbf{a} \boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{b}\right)
\end{equation*}
Note that for $\:\boldsymbol{\mathrm{M}}\:$  a real orthonormal matrix
\begin{equation*}
\boldsymbol{\mathrm{M}}\boldsymbol{\mathrm{M}}^{\mathsf{T}}=\boldsymbol{\mathrm{I}} \quad \Longrightarrow \quad \boldsymbol{\mathrm{M}}^{-1}=\boldsymbol{\mathrm{M}}^{\mathsf{T}} \text{ and }  \det\left(\boldsymbol{\mathrm{M}}\right)=\pm 1  
\end{equation*}
and equation (B-02) yields as expected
\begin{equation}
 \left(\boldsymbol{\mathrm{M}}\mathbf{a} \boldsymbol{\times} \boldsymbol{\mathrm{M}}\mathbf{b}\right) =\pm\boldsymbol{\mathrm{M}}\left(\mathbf{a} \boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{b}\right)
\end{equation}
The '+' sign is valid for $\:\boldsymbol{\mathrm{M}}\:$ being a pure rotation while  the '-' sign is valid for $\:\boldsymbol{\mathrm{M}}\:$  a rotation plus a reflection.

Comment: I am really impressed by the level of detail of your notes (I personnaly also write notes with the aim of writing sthg "so clear that is impossible not to understand" but I have to say that I sometimes skip things). Let me give here a hint to a direct proof of (A-9), (A-10): $\Omega^i_j= - \epsilon^i_{jk}\omega^k,\quad \omega^{'k}= u^k_l\omega^l\quad \Rightarrow\quad \Omega^{'i}_j=-\epsilon^i_{jk} u^k_l\omega^l$. The trick lies in the following formula based on the explicit expression of the determinant : $\epsilon_{ijk} = \epsilon_{abc}u^a_i u^b_j u^c_k$. "Multiply" both side with $u^k_p$...

Comment: I have cheated a little bit in the formula, which is mention e.g. in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/815278/determinant-with-levi-civita-symbol. I have already used $det (u)=1$ or more exactly $det(u^T)=1$, so yeah, let's call this a vague hint.

Comment: I'm actually looking at the http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms site so that we can discuss (i've never used it), I think it is more appropriate than long comments. Yes I also want both very detailed calculus but also the abstract thing. for the "lucky" part, I don't know... "this is not always possible" I don't understand?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24456/discussion-between-user39158-and-diracpaul).

Comment: @diracpaul Note that you can use the syntax `\tag{text here}` to produce equation tags.