# How to decompose tensor products of $SU(3)$ representations?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, quantum-chromodynamics

Formally, one can arrange the quark flavors in a $SU(n)$ fundamental representation. One can then do tensor products for flavor and spin to construct other representations like baryons and mesons. An example: $2⊗2=3⊕1$ for spin $SU(2)$ gives scalar and vector mesons, $3⊗\overline3=8⊕1$ for flavor $SU(3)$ gives the eightfold way for both scalar and vector mesons.

My question is easy: how do you get $3⊗\overline3=8⊕1$? Or for baryons: $3⊗3⊗3=10⊕8⊕8⊕1$?

Comment: Do these answer your question? [Decomposing a Tensor Product of $SU(3)$ Representations in Irreps](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/57607/decomposing-a-tensor-product-of-su3-representations-in-irreps) and [$\mathrm{SU(3)}$ decomposition of $\mathbf{3} \otimes \mathbf{\bar{3}} = \mathbf{8} \oplus \mathbf{1}$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89173)

Comment: thank you, but I found no explanation on how to actually calculate this case