# How does hexagonal boundary arise in $SU(3)$ representation?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, quarks

I am having trouble trying to understand the hexagonal boundary in $t_3$ and $y$ representation of $SU (3)$. I tried to work it out like we did in $SU \left( 2 \right)$ but got not luck. Could someone please explain the routine of understanding this? I appreciate that.

By the way, I did not post my work because it did not work, I can post my work if people are curious.

Comment: Related $SU(3)$ post: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10403/2451 and links therein; especially the answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/14586/2451 .

Comment: Do you understand what the root system of $SU(3)$ looks like?

Comment: It would be constructive to have a little more details as it’s it clear what you mean by $t_3$ and $y$ representation.