# Some ambiguity regarding irreducible tensors in $SU(3)$

Tags: symmetry, tensor-calculus, group-theory, representation-theory

I'm studying the tensor methods in $SU(N)$ and decided to work through [Georgi book](https://books.google.com/books?id=g4yEuH5rBMUC&redir_esc=y), namely chapter 10. As far as I can tell, the point is to decompose a tensor to irreducible components; symmetric and asymmetric (traceless) part. For that we can use the fact that $\delta^j_i$, $\varepsilon_{ijk}$ and $\varepsilon^{ijk}$ are invariant tensors under $SU(3)$.

The first example is decomposing a tensor product of $(1,0) \otimes (1,0) := \mathbf{3} \otimes \mathbf{3}$. Using the notation, that lower indices in states $|_i\rangle$ indicate the states in $\mathbf{3}$, we construct general tensor as $u^iv^j$, which we can decompose to symmetric and antisymmetric part:

$$
u^iv^j = \frac{1}{2}\left(u^iv^j + u^jv^i\right) - \frac{1}{2}\varepsilon^{ijk}\varepsilon_{jlm}u^lv^m.
$$

Now, if I understand correctly, the first part $\left(u^iv^j + u^jv^i\right)$ is irreducible because it's symmetric and the second part is irreducible because it's antisymmetric. But they're not traceless, so that's where I'm unsure. Are we looking to construct a sum of just symmetric and antisymmetric tensors? Because in the next example $\mathbf{3} \otimes \mathbf{\bar{3}}$, where we decompose $u^iv_j$ as

$$
u^iv_j = \left( u^iv_j - \frac{1}{3}\delta^i_ju^kv_k \right) - \frac{1}{3}\delta^i_ju^kv_k
$$
that is $u^iv_j = $ 'traceless' + 'invariant tensor'.

To recap; what exactly are we looking for when decomposing a tensor in $SU(3)$ or $SU(N)$ for that matter? Why don't we subtract the trace in the first example, but we do exactly that in the second.

I have some more follow up questions, but I believe the common agreement is not to pose multiple questions in one thread.

Comment: you subtract what you *can*. In the first expression there is nothing left you can subtract, so it is irreducible. In order to subtract a trace here, you'd need $\delta_{ij}$, but this is not an $\mathfrak{su}$-invariant symbol. So you leave it as is.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Because we'd need a lower index component to use $\delta^i_j$ which is invariant, right? This would make sense to me. In either case, the goal is to decompose to symmetric, antisymmetric and the $\delta^i_j$ terms?

Comment: well, if you have more indices $u^{ijk}$ things become more complicated. The irreps have partial symmetry/antisymmetry. There are [algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Littlewood%E2%80%93Richardson_rule) for how to decompose a given rep into irreps, but this is really a math question at this point.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10403/2451 and links therein.

Comment: You've seen this before, haven't you, in *SU(2)* , angular momentum, $\mathbf{3} \otimes \mathbf{3}.$  That is, the addition of two spin 1s, has a triplet antisymmetric part;  a quintet and a singlet in the symmetric part: spin 2 and spin 1.