# how can a particle can have a spin of 2

Tags: particle-physics, quantum-spin, fermions, color-charge

i have seen some analogies of spin using playing cards but i am struggling to grasp the concept due to this making no sense in terms of playing cards

Comment: For color, see [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2228/50583).

Comment: this still leaves how a particle can have a spin of 2

Comment: What do you mean, "how"? From Noldorin's answer: *"Specifically, the allowed values of the spin quantum number s are non-negative multiples of 1/2."* Don't cling to that card analogy, it's just an analogy that breaks down if you think about it too hard. Spin is a technical term with a very precise technical meaning.

Comment: ok, so the card idea is not a good one that does not work too well. i'll just accept that it can happen considering that it is not literally referring to spin as something like a card. having a spin of 2 does fit the explanation you directed me to.

Comment: You can help us by describing the analogy with playing cards that you refer to.  At least one of us has never seen it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hear that analogy too. 
Spin 0: any rotation left the "object" invariant, like a circle who rotates.
Spin 1/2: half rotation to het the initial state of the object, and here we are: any figure of the playing card "has spin 1/2".

Spin 1: any non figure card, like who knows, the ace of clubs. One integer rotation to get is as it was initially.

Spin 2: no example in playing cards. But you may think about the Moebius strip. You have to make 2 rounds to get back to the initial state/position. This is the best analogy for spin 2.

Now we should have to find an analogy for spin 3/2 :D

Comment: what about a hyper cube?

Comment: Don't you have it backwards? I'm pretty sure the playing card is spin $2$ and the spin $\frac{1}{2}$ is where it starts to get tricky (because fermions are represented by spinors not vectors).